# does Lenovo fingerprint reader work in ubuntu?

Tags: thinkpad, fingerprint-reader

I'd like to know if anyone out there has a Lenovo laptop with the fingerprint reader. I was wondering if the reader works on ubuntu?

Comment: There's no "the fingerprint reader". There are various models which need different ways to enable them. That said, please include the output of following command (open a gnome-terminal and run it) in your question: `lsusb`.

Comment: Not on my Lenovo computer.

Answer (score 4):

Scratch my last answer... I managed to get this working with the following PPA in 10.10:

[Launchpad fingerprint-gui](https://launchpad.net/~fingerprint/+archive/fingerprint-gui)

Just follow the directions, but before you log out, open up the finterprint-gui to see what brand device you have so you know if you'll need the proprietary libraries or not.

Comment: Thanks for that. Just got an older Lenovo t60 with fingerprint reader and was keen /sad enough to see if it works....and it does. I thought I was on Star Trek, my son was unimpressed

Comment: Sad it is not working out of the box.

Comment: This tool seems to be outdated?

Comment: @Soerendip Given the answer is from 2011, I'm not surprised.  fingerprint reader support has come a long way in Ubuntu since then and several are enabled by default.  In a lot of cases, you can open Settings, go to Users, choose the desired user and toggle the "fingerprint login" option.

Comment: I think, there is no such option.