# finger-print-gui and lenovo x220 fingerprint reader issue

Tags: thinkpad, fingerprint-reader

in part related to
[does Lenovo fingerprint reader work in ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/36319/does-lenovo-fingerprint-reader-work-in-ubuntu?rq=1)

i did follow the several instructions one can find on here and elsewhere.
i succeeded also in enrolling my index finger with the gui
and with running pam-uth-update
activated the fingerprint-reader for login or sudo commands

whenever i now boot the machine or give sudo commands i get a command shown to 
identify with my finger.
the LED of the fingerprint-reader also SHORTLY lights up and then goes off.

SOMETIMES logging in like that works
most of the times it does not work

i am sure this has to do with the led being on for short moment only.

but why?? any log to check??

btw: works fine in windows 7 so hardware is okay
and lusb also shows my reader is supported by finger-print-gui

Comment: I have a HP HDX16 with a fingerprint scanner using the Fingerprint GUI, and I've noticed that it is tougher to get it to recognize me than when I boot into Win7 on the same machine. Maybe the Fingerprint GUI is using a more strict policy for comparison.

Comment: yes, maybe. because in windows i never fail. but especially that the LED often goes out quickly is something i cannot understand. maybe driver related?

Comment: Are you still interested in this question?

Comment: for now i did give up with logging into my lubuntu with fingerprint-reader. but am open to try again to secure my system better